# Prove $\frac1{2πi}\int_C\frac{ζ^2(1-n)z^{-n}}{2\cos(nπ/2)}\,{\rm d}n=-γ-\frac12\log z-\frac1{4πz}+\frac zπ\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+∞}\frac{τ(n)}{z^2+n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, number-theory

I'm wondering on how one can go about proving that

$$\frac{1}{2\pi \imath} \int_{\left(\mathcal{C}\right)} \frac{\zeta^2(1-n)\,z^{-n}}{2\cos\left(n\pi /2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}n = -\gamma -\frac12 \log z - \frac{1}{4\pi z}+\frac{z}{\pi}\sum_{n= 1}^{+\infty} \frac{\tau(n)}{z^2+n^2}$$
where $\tau(n)$ represents the divisor function, $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant, $\zeta$ represents the Riemann zeta function, $1<\mathcal{C}<2$ and $\int_{(\mathcal{C})}$ denotes the line integral $\int_{\mathcal{C}-\imath \infty}^{\mathcal{C} + \imath\infty}$.

So far I tried complex analytic methods (Residue theorem and contour integration) but no progress.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the condition on $\mathcal{C}$? It may be useful to know that $$
\zeta ^2 (s) = \sum\limits_{k = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{\tau (k)}}{{k^s }}} 
$$ for $\Re s>1$.

Comment: @Gary I ahve updated the question: $2>\mathcal{C}>1$. How do you exactly plan on using the series for $\zeta^2(s)$? Could you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried pushing the contour through $\Re n =1$ towards $-\infty$ and picking up the residues?

Comment: @Gary Yes but it didn't work out well for me

Comment: @Permutator Please don't use math-only titles. The context menu of the browser does not load when right-clicked; the context menu of MathJax does. See [this post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730/888233) for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say shift the contour to the left to reach the region where $\zeta(1-s)^2=\sum_{m\ge 1} \tau(m) m^{s-1}$ converges absolutely and uniformly on the vertical lines.

No problem to do so because $\zeta(s)$ is $O(|s|^r)$ in the vertical strip so the exponential decay of $1/\cos(\pi s/2)$ makes it ok.

This will add two residues at $0$ and $1$.

Then use the absolute/uniform convergence to say that $$\int_{(-1/2)} \frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2 \cos(\pi s/2)} z^{-s}ds=\sum_{m\ge 1} \tau(m)\int_{(-1/2)} \frac{m^{s-1}}{2 \cos(\pi s/2)} z^{-s}ds$$
Where the last integral is easily computed with the residue theorem,  for $z\in (0,1)$:

$$\int_{(-1/2)} \frac{m^{s-1}}{2 \cos(\pi s/2)} z^{-s}ds = 2i\pi \sum_{k=0}^\infty Res(\frac{m^{s-1}}{2 \cos(\pi s/2)} z^{-s},-2k-1)$$ $$=
2i \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{m^{-2k-2}}{(-1)^k} z^{2k+1}
 = \frac{2i z}{m^2+z^2}
$$

You can extend to the remaining $z\in \Bbb{C}-i \Bbb{Z}_{\ge 1}$ by analytic continuation.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2\cos\left(\pi s/2\right)}=\frac{1}{2\cos\left(\pi s/2\right)}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\tau(n)}{n^{1-s}}\ ,\ \Re(s)<0\tag{1}$$

which according to both WolframAlpha and Mathematica leads to:

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2\cos\left(\pi s/2\right)}\,x^{-s}\,ds=\frac{x}{\pi}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{\tau(n)}{x^2+n^2}\tag{2}$$.

---

See [WolframAlpha evaluation of the relevant inverse Mellin transform](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=InverseMellinTransform%5B1%2F%282%20Cos%5B%5C%5BPi%5D%20s%2F2%5D%29%20%5C%5BTau%5D%5Bn%5D%2Fn%5E%281%20-%20s%29%2C%20s%2C%20x%5D) where $\tau(n)=\sigma_0(n)$. Mathematica provides the same result as WolframAlpha and indicates the result is valid for $-1<\Re(s)<1$, but I'm wondering if $-1<c<0$ should really be the condition on formula (2) above.

---

Note formula (2) above omits the $-\gamma-\frac12\log x$ and $-\frac{1}{4 \pi x}$ terms associated with the residues of $\frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2\cos\left(\pi s/2\right)}\,x^{-s}$ at $s=0$ and $s=1$ respectively, but these terms also need to be included according to a comment by [@Gary](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/83800/gary) below and the alternate answer posted by [@reuns](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/276986/reuns) which also provides a derivation of the right-side of formula (2) above.

---

The approach taken above (which is also echoed in the alternate answer posted by @reuns) doesn't seem to directly address the question since the OP expressed a desire to evaluate the inverse Mellin transform specified on the left-side of formula (2) above where $1<c<2$.

---

Note that

$$\frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}=2^{1-2 s} \pi ^{-2 s} \cos \left(\frac{\pi  s}{2}\right) \Gamma (s)^2 \sum _{n=1}^\infty\frac{\tau(n)}{n^s}\ ,\ \Re(s)>1\tag{3}$$

which according to Mathematica leads to

$$\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \frac{\zeta(1-s)^2}{2 \cos\left(\frac{\pi s}{2}\right)}\,x^{-s}\,ds=\sum _{n=1}^\infty\tau(n)\ G_{0,4}^{3,0}\left(n \pi ^2 x,\frac{1}{2}|
\begin{array}{c}
 0,0,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right)\tag{4}$$

where $G$ is the [MeijerG function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html).

---

Mathematica indicates the result in formula (4) above is valid for $\Re(s)>0$, but I'm wondering if $c>1$ should really be the condition on formula (4) above.

Comment: The contour $\mathcal{C}$ is on the right of $\Re s =1$, so you have to push it through $s=0,1$ to reach $\Re s<0$. In this way you also pick up the residues from those two points.

Comment: @Gary I'm used to evaluating inverse Mellin transforms like $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int\limits_{c-i\infty}^{c+i\infty} \log\zeta(s)\,\frac{x^s}{s}\,ds$ where $c>1$ (note $x^s$ in the integral here versus $x^{-s}$ in the integral in the answer above). Are you saying the WolframAlpha result is wrong?

Comment: @Gary The WolframAlpha evaluation of the inverse Mellin transform is consistent with it's evaluation of the corresponding Mellin transform (see https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=MellinTransform%5Bx%2F%5C%5BPi%5D+%5C%5BTau%5D%5Bn%5D%2F%28x%5E2+%2B+n%5E2%29%2C+x%2C+s%5D), so it seems to me if one of the evaluations is wrong both of the evaluations must be wrong.

Comment: I just do not understand the first part of your answer. You substitute a series valid for $\Re s<0$, but initially $1 <\Re s <2$ on the contour specified by the OP. You have to push the OP's contour through the singularities at $s=0,1$ to reach the region $\Re s<0$ where you can substitute the series. Perhaps I just misunderstood what you wrote.

Comment: @Gary I changed the integral limits in my answer above and didn't specify the value of $c$ since I'm not sure what value is used by WolframAlpha to evaluate the inverse Mellin transform, but Mathematica provides the same result and indicates the result is valid for $-1<\Re(s)<1$.